# Is it possible to set multiple default arguments to a method that return multiple values?

Tags: ruby

I have a method which is basically as this:

```
def myMethod(a, b)
  # do stuff
end
```

Normally, if I call a method that returns multiple values, I would simply do:

```
a, b = otherMethod
```

How would it be possible to apply that to the default arguments of myMethod, WITHOUT having to use an Array ? I could be wrong about performance issues, but the reason is simply because I want to avoid creating new Array objects as this method is called very often. I'm aware I could also write:

```
a, b = otherMethod
myMethod(a, b)
```

However, I'd have no default argument at all and the code would grow larger since it's called from multiple lines. I would like to know if there's a way to do it with such syntax within the arguments.

Comment: When you return multiple values like `a, b = foo`, aren't you already returning an array from `foo`? This seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) -- if you can provide more context, there's probably a better solution since returning multiple values tends to be an antipattern. Probably, you need a struct that can be passed around, or some other data structure/class that has multiple member functions that can manipulate its data over time, without allocation and without verbose unpacking/repacking syntax.

Comment: Do you mean `myMethod(*otherMethod)` ?

Comment: I'm not dealing with complex values, only 2 Numeric ones by using return a, b. If you're saying that whether I assign an equal or not number of variables to the returned values, a new Array is still created each time, the syntax I'm looking for would be irrelevant. I thought that doing a, b = foo, if foo returns 2 values, would avoid that.

Comment: Methods always return exactly one object. If you write `a, b = m` the method `m` returns an array and the variables `a` and `b` are assigned values from the array by the application of [array decompostion](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).